# Laravel/PHPUnit: how mock param for method (or for constructor controller itself)?

Tags: laravel, mocking, phpunit

Preamble: I'm developing with Laravel 5.7 and Repository/Gateway pattern.

Using dependency injection, I can mock and test my own classes without really depending from external library.

This is the underline method:

```
/**
     * @param Ip $ip
     * @return string
     * @throws ConnectionError
     * @throws ServiceError
     */
    public function fetchPublicIp(Ip $ip)
    {
        try {
            $public_ip = $ip::get();
            return $public_ip;
        } catch (ConnectionError $e) {
            // If you get here, it means you were unable to reach the ipify service,
            // most likely because of a network error on your end.
            //echo $e->getMessage();
            //return $e;
            throw new ConnectionError();
        } catch (ServiceError $e) {
            // If you get here, it means ipify is having issues, so the request
            // couldn't be completed :(
            throw new ServiceError();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Something else happened (non-ipify related).
            throw new \Exception();
        }
    }
```

And in effect this is well-tested with

```
/**
     * READ (external)
     * Test that we can get external public IP
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_can_get_public_ip()
    {
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

        $mock = Mockery::mock('Ipify\Ip');

        $mock->shouldReceive('get')
            ->andReturn($this->faker->ipv4())
            ->mock();

        $this->assertTrue(class_exists('Ipify\Ip'));
        $this->assertTrue($mock instanceof Ip);
        $gateway = $this->app->make('App\Gateways\PublicIPGateway');
        $public_ip = $gateway->fetchPublicIp($mock);
        $this->assertIsString(filter_var($public_ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP));
    }
```

Now, my doubt.

I'm writing an API that calls the `gateway` method `fetchPublicIp`.

```
    PubliIpApiController.php

    /**
     * Update the Public Ip stored in database
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function update(Ip $ipify)
    {
        $public_ip = $this->getGateway()->fetchPublicIp($ipify);
        // other stuffes here
        return response()->json([
            'public_ip' => $public_ip
        ]);
    }
```

But, we are at starting point. I can test the `update` method directly, mocking the external `Ip` class.

But, how can I test directly the my own API call?

Stub test is

```
<?php
[...]
$response = $this->get(Route('public_ip_update'));
[...]
?>
```

But, of course, with this call I am really coupled (newly) to the external IP.

So, how can I mock the `Ip` external class to pass the mock as parameter for `updatePublicIp`?

Another idea I got is to move the dependency from the method to `__construct()` of Controller, but, the problem is the same: how mock only the constructor for controller?

A pseudocode:

```
$mock = new Mock('Ipify\Ip');
$public_ip_controller = new PublicIpController($gateway, $mock)
$response = $this->get(Route('public_ip_update'));
```